# How can I append attributes to current value in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert HTML formatting into CSS via XSL for accessibility purposes. I've got it working but only if there is no style attribute previously there. How would I add an attribute to a style tag that is already there? This is my code for changing `align=` to `style="text-align:` when there is no style attribute:

```
<!-- /align -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@align">
<xsl:attribute name="style">
<xsl:value-of select="@style"/>
<xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('text-align: ',.)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I thought the previous attributes would be included by using value-of before concatting, but it's not working. I want this to be able to add `text-align:` even if there is a style tag already there, like `style="border: 1px; text-align:`

**Edit:**

This is the updated code this is giving me an error:

```
<!-- /align -->


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@align]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'style' or local-name() = 'align')]" />
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
                <xsl:if test="@style and substring(@style, string-length(@style)) != ';'">; </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@align" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@align">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align: ', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- /width -->

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@width]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'style' or local-name() = 'width')]" />
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
                <xsl:if test="@style and substring(@style, string-length(@style)) != ';'">; </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@width" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@width">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('width: ', . , 'px')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

I'm guessing this error is happening because I'm trying to add another attribute to an element that's already been altered with one of these transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need to do is match the parent element, rather than the attributes themselves, and then add a new `style` attribute, using the contents of any existing one, as well as then appending the `align` attribute.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@align]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'style' or local-name() = 'align')]" />
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
        <xsl:if test="@style and substring(@style, string-length(@style)) != ';'">;</xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@align" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@align">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align: ', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could simplify the template just a little...

```
<xsl:template match="*[@align]">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@style, @align)" />
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
    <xsl:if test="@style and not(ends-with(@style, ';'))">;</xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@align" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This works like a charm. However, if I add more than two to the file, I get an error: Problem during transform: An attribute node (style) cannot be created after a child of the containing element. Any idea why?

Comment: @salsaverde - Make sure your `xsl:attribute`'s are all before the `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. (The other `apply-templates` is ok because it's selecting attribute nodes only.)

Comment: @DanielHaley That's not possible, right? I'm doing this for multiple attributes like border, align, frameborder, width, height, etc. That means I need multiple `<xsl:template match="x">`

Comment: @salsaverde - Is it possible to update your question with the new code that's causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider maybe using moded templates (using the `mode` attribute) for the attributes.

Here's a XSLT 1.0 example (2.0+ can be simplified)...

**XML Input**

```
<test align="center" width="100"/>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- This is the identity transform and is only needed once. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@align or @width]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name()='style') and 
                                      not(local-name()='align') and 
                                      not(local-name()='width')]"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
        <xsl:if test="@style and substring(@style, string-length(@style)) != ';'">; </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="style"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@align" mode="style">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('text-align: ', ., ';')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@width" mode="style">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('width: ', . , 'px', ';')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="style"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<test style="text-align: center;width: 100px;"/>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVP/1

Comment: This did work in terms of appending them all, but it duplicated the current content in the style attribute and somehow threw the src in there, too. for example, i have `<img src="/test/image.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;">` and the transform resulted in `<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; /test/image.jpgdisplay: block; margin-left: auto; width: 600px; height: 400px;">`

Comment: @salsaverde - Oops. Forgot the default match for the style mode. Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you!!! You just saved me from having to change HTML to CSS formatting on each one of our 15,000 pages. Life saver.

Comment: @salsaverde - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. :-)

Comment: Hi! Quick followup question. If I add a table to my code/that fiddle, it throws an error. It seems like the transform isn't reaching nested elements. Do you have an idea of why that is? I've tried playing around with different template match combinations to no avail.

Comment: @salsaverde - I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please update the fiddle and add a link as a comment?

Comment: @salsaverde - it's because the input xml isn't well-formed; you can only have one root element. Here's an updated version with a single root element: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVP/4

Comment: I see! But this also doesn't work: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVP/5. All I did was close the p tag before the table.

Comment: @salsaverde - In that example you still have two root elements; `table` and `p`. This will cause an error with any XSLT you use.